# Use elements of list to index/subset other list in R

Tags: r, list, indexing

Is it possible to run the following code without a loop (preferably something like lapply)?

```
vec1=c(.1,.2,.3,.4,.5)
vec2=c(2,4,6,8,10)

vec3<-c(1,5)
vec4<-c(2,4)

lijst<-list(vec1,vec2)
lijst2<-list(vec3,vec4)

for (i in 1:2) { 
print(lijst[[i]][lijst2[[i]]])
}
```

This is part of a much larger algorithm where I need to optimize to reduce computation time.

** EDIT **

In the end I want to set the elements indicated in *lijst2* to zero, so the final solution should be the following list:

```
[[1]]
[1] 0 0.2 0.3 0.4 0

[[2]]
[1]  2  0  6  0 10
```

Comment: `lapply(1:2, function(i) print(lijst[[i]][lijst2[[i]]]))`

Comment: Do you need to put the vectors into lists for other reasons? Otherwise, you could just run `vec1[vec3]` and `vec2[vec4]` to get the same results.

Comment: Thank you both for the quick reply, I edited my original post to indicate what my final goal is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give the expected output:

```
mapply(function(x,y) {x[y]=0;x},x=lijst,y=lijst2,SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

output:

```
[[1]]
[1] 0.0 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.0

[[2]]
[1]  2  0  6  0 10
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to start with the list. The `vec` statements were just to give reproducable code. As I mentioned, this is part of a larger algorithm were it is set up as a list.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand that. You can achieve that with mapply, see my updated answer. Hope this helps!

Comment: A more standard way is `Map(replace, lijst, lijst2, 0)`, I guess.

Comment: That looks a lot simpler indeed. Not really familiar with the mapply/Map functions yet..